# Laravel Relationship with 4 Table

Tags: laravel, relationship

I've got 4 tables:

users
teams
locations
users_teams

my teams table has relationship with locations. (it has location_id field)
users and teams have belongsToMany relationship with users_teams.
users doesn't have directly relationship with locations.

But I need to get coaches in this location.
It means; "get me all coaches; which are belongs to teams of that location"

But couldnt move any to make this.
How can this be possible?

how my "coaches" function of my "Location" model?

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

If your relationships are set up correctly, and assuming you have an enum column named `type` with `coach` as a possible value, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$coaches = User::where('type', 'coach')
    ->whereHas('teams.locations', function($query)
    {
        $query->where('name', 'some place');
    })->get();
```